# How to Separate jQuery Functions w/o Using 2 Script Tags

Tags: jquery

I'm not 100% knowledgeable in JS or jQuery, and have a question about how to separate functions.

I currently have this function:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

  console.log(wScroll)

  var windowWidth = ($(window).width() / 8);
  var windowHeight = ($(window).height() / 16);

  $('.fore-card').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + windowWidth*0 + 'px, ' + windowHeight*(-6) + 'px)',
  });
  $('.mid-card').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + windowWidth*(-1) + 'px, ' + windowHeight + 'px)',
  });
  $('.back-card').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + windowWidth*(2) + 'px, ' + windowHeight*(-12) + 'px)',
  });

});
```

As you can see I have a listener for the scroll. I also have functions that have nothing to do with the scroll of the page. Now it does work, however the scroll is causing some jankiness with my objects, hence why I need to separate them.

I initially thought something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        func1();
        func2();
        [...etc...];
});
```

Would do it...but I'm not sure how to go about this.

***UPDATE***

Based off of the comments, am I to assume that this would work:

```
$(function(){

  var windowWidth = ($(window).width() / 8);
  var windowHeight = ($(window).height() / 16);

  $('.fore-card').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + windowWidth*0 + 'px, ' + windowHeight*(-6) + 'px)',
  });
  $('.mid-card').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + windowWidth*(-1) + 'px, ' + windowHeight + 'px)',
  });
  $('.back-card').css({
    'transform': 'translate(' + windowWidth*(2) + 'px, ' + windowHeight*(-12) + 'px)',
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

    console.log(wScroll)

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is as simple as listing two functions, you can do exactly what you were thinking:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        //your scroll function
    });

    //anything else
    // you can put functions, modules, object literals, etc. 

    var module = {
        func1 : function(){

        },
        func2 : function(){

        }
    };

    $("#someDiv").on( "click", module.func1 );
});
```

As @A.B. notes, you can use IIEFs to avoid polluting the global namespace. If your app grows larger, you can use a namespace for it, e.g. application:

```
var application = {};
application.main = ( function( $ ) {
    //module internals
    var count = 1,
    _someInternalFunc = function(){

    };

    //return public variables
    return{
      count: count,
      func1: function(){

      },
      func2: function(){

      }
    };
}( jQuery ) );
```

And you can move your modules (e.g. application.main) into their own files and include them with a dependency loader so they load in proper order. Study functions, namespaces, module pattern, and dependency loaders. Also, study the new ES6 module format, as it will become the standard way to create modular, exportable functions in JavaScript.

Comment: Ok. I re-editted my original question seconds after you posted this. Would that give me the results I need?

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap parts of code in Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) that needs separation of concerns

```
$(document).ready(function(){


           (function () {
          //somecode here
           }());

           (function () {
          //some other code here
           }());


});
```

Comment: Agree, or just create plain old JS functions:

Comment: @DaveKaye yes that will work too, but i doubt they can pollute the common scope variables etc

Comment: Well but then that's when you need a better plan. Functions are a basic building block of code that jQuery lets you use without really learning how they work.  Reading up on them a bit might help the OP see how easily the problem can be solved...